# Jquery UI in Phalcon

Tags: php, jquery-ui, phalcon

I am currently using Phalcon framework, and i have problem when i want to use jquery-ui.
Here is my code for index.phtml view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#test").dialog();
 });  
</script>

<html>
<body>
<p id="test">Hello.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can enyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I included scripts like this: <?php

    echo Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("js/jquery.min.js");
    echo Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/jquery.js");
    echo Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("js/jquery-ui.js");
   echo Phalcon\Tag::stylesheetLink("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css", false);
echo Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js", false);
    
    
?>

Comment: 1. What is exactly wrong?
2. Can you post entire example?

Comment: You seem to have a minor error in your declarations of `stylesheetLink` and `javascriptInclude`. You have 2 commas in there making `false` the third parameter. Also load up the site in Chrome and press F12 to get the tools that would give you more information on what has been loaded and what not.

Comment: oh it was when i paste a code